# Combine function came from ownProps in mapDispatchToProps

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

In my react component, I want to be able to combine the standard actions and the functions I receive through ownProps? How do I do that? A follow up question is that in ownProps, I could get objects as well as functions. I want to make sure that I do not accidentally try to put an object into my actions. Only the functions should go into my actions.

So ultimately, I should be able to type `this.props.actions.standardAction1` or `this.props.actions.actionReceivedThruOwnProps`.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';

import * as standardActions from '../actions/standardActions';

class MyComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props);
    }

    render() {

        return(
            <div>Something goes here...</div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        something: state.something
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, ownProps) {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(standardActions, dispatch)
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have full control on how final props passed to you component will look like. `react-redux` allow you to do so using third argument to `connect` decorator/function.

Define function, which will receive mapped state from `mapStateToProps`, bound actions from `mapDispatchToProps` and own props passed to component from parent. Then, merge them as you wish.

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        something: state.something,
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, ownProps) {
    return {
        ...bindActionCreators(standardActions, dispatch),
    };
}

function mergeProps(stateProps, dispatchProps, ownProps) {
    return {
        ...ownProps,
        state: stateProps,
        actions: {
            ...dispatchProps,
            ...ownProps.actions,
        },
    };
}

connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps,
    mergeProps
)(SuperComponent)
```

Comment: For some reason, this is not combining all the actions under "props.actions". I see the function that I pass as "this.props.myFunction" but NOT "this.props.actions.myFunction". Not that big a deal but ultimately I wanted to combine all of them under "actions". Any idea why it may fail to combine them?

Comment: Write down shape of props passed to component, `mapStateToProps`, `mapDispatchToProps` and finally `mergeProps` so that we can see how you combine them.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this but I'm not really sure on how the function exists in ownProps:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, ownProps) {
    return {
        actions: {
         ...bindActionCreators(standardActions, dispatch),     
         ...ownProps
        }
    };
}
```

check this too, if you want to separate actions from functions came from ownProps:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, ownProps) {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(standardActions, dispatch),     
        ownProps: ownProps,
        }
    };
}
```

and then you call it like that : `this.props.ownProps.actionReceivedThruOwnProps`

Comment: I still need to figure out how to separate objects from functions but this will help me move forward now. Sometimes the simplicity of solutions boggles my mind! Thanks again!